# Run Function When a Scroll Event Does NOT Happen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animation that I want to fire under 2 circumstances:

1. When the page loads for the first time and the browser does not auto-scroll
2. When the page is refreshed and the browser auto-scrolls the user back to their previous position, and that position (`scrollTop()`) is less than `300`.

I do **not** want the event to fire if:

1. The user refreshes the page and the browser auto-scrolls to a position that is more than `300`.

The only way (that I know) to detect a browser auto-scroll is to fire this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(this).one('scroll', function(){
        var pagePosition = $('html').scrollTop();
    }
});
```

However if I run this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // run on original page load (no scroll)
    myAnimation();

    // run on page refresh w/ auto-scroll
    $(window).one('scroll', function(){
        var pagePosition = $('html').scrollTop();

        if( pagePosition < 300 ) {
            myAnimation();
        }
    }
}
```

The animation will be fired twice on an original page load. Once when the page is loaded, and again when the user starts scrolling.

I need some way to detect if the browser auto-scrolls on load, and if it *doesn't*, then run the animation once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this different than simply scrolling on load only if the scroll position is less than 300, e.g.:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var pagePosition = $('body').scrollTop();

        if( pagePosition < 300 ) {
            myAnimation();
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

Note that you should measure the `scrollTop` from the `<body>` element rather than `<html>` since some browsers always assign `<html>` a scroll position of `0`.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathomas/Vn2eR/5/)

Comment: That seems to be really inconsistent from browser to browser. Chrome will always give a 0 until a scroll event is fired, Firefox gives the position immediately, and Safari gives a 0 every time, scroll or no.

Comment: Ah, should have looked at what I copied and pasted. There's an error in your code. Will update my answer.

Comment: Still no. All browsers report "0" regardless of auto-scrolling.

Comment: If your page is complex, you can add a `setTimeout()` to give the browser time to scroll. More updates and a working example, but if you need more help than this, I'll have to start charging my hourly rate.